# I am trying to analyse a dataset using RStudio and although I am getting some output , I don't what this error is or how it's affecting my code

Tags: r

I am getting this error in my code . Can anyone please explain me what it is . I am  new to R and RStudio.

CODE -

```
# Import the dataset into an R data frame
dataset <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ariha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\archive\\flixpatrol.csv")

# Display the structure of the data frame
str(dataset)

# Display the first few rows of the dataset
head(dataset)

# Summarize basic statistics for numerical variables
summary(dataset)

# Subset the data based on a condition
subset_data <- dataset[dataset$Rank > 50, ]

# Create a new variable or column
dataset$new_variable <- dataset$Watch_time_in_Million * 2

# Filter the data based on specific criteria
filtered_data <- subset(dataset, Genre == "Value")

# Calculate mean, median, and standard deviation
mean_value <- mean(dataset$Watch_time_in_Million)
median_value <- median(dataset$Watch_time_in_Million)
sd_value <- sd(dataset$Watch_time_in_Million)

# Tabulate frequencies for categorical variables
table(dataset$Type)

# Create a histogram for a numeric variable
hist(dataset$Watch_time_in_Million, main = "Distribution of Watch Time", xlab = "Watch Time (Million)")

# Create a bar plot for a categorical variable
barplot(table(dataset$Genre), main = "Frequency of Genres")
```

ERROR -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoJrD.png)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new_variable, value = numeric(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 18164

I don't know what this error is representing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Most likely reason is that there is no column with name `Watch_time_in_Million` in `dataset`. Perhaps because of a typo? Check the column names. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(head(dataset))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example as stefan suggested would certainly be helpful here. Remove as much code as possible while keeping the original error. It will help you, and us, to narrow down where the problem is.